# JavaScript 'input multiple' file duplication

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, input

This is my code:

```
        var rowData = [];

        var showFiles = function () {
            var input = document.getElementById('doc-upload');
            if (input.files.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i += 1) {
                    rowData.push([input.files[i].name]);
                };
                console.log(rowData);
            };
        };
        document.getElementById('doc-upload').addEventListener('change', showFiles, this);
```

'rowData' recives a normal value for the first time i upload some thing.
At the second try it starts to duplicate incoming values.

If i uploaded 1 file first try it's ok.
Second time i wold get 2 same files.
Third 4 files, exetera.

Why this is happening?

UPD:

More explanations:
What happaning is: i upload x.doc my array is [x.doc], now i want to upload y.doc. I choose y.doc and my array turns in to [x.doc, y.doc, y.doc], then i upload z.doc and aaray looks like [x.doc, y.doc, y.doc, z.doc, z.doc, z.doc, z.doc]. And so on. It have to do some thing with length property, i messed it up some how.

UPD2:

Now the full version of the code:

```
    //file upload
    var rowData = [];
    docAddButton.addListener('click', function () {
        var showFiles = function () {
            var input = document.getElementById('doc-upload');
            if (input.files.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i += 1) {
                    if (rowData.indexOf(true, input.files[i].name, Math.round(input.files[i].size * 0.001) + ' кб') === -1) {
                        rowData.push([
                            true,
                            input.files[i].name, 
                            Math.round(input.files[i].size * 0.001) + ' кб'
                        ]);
                    }
                }
                console.log(rowData);
                tableModel.setData(rowData);
            };
        };
        document.getElementById('doc-upload').addEventListener('change', showFiles, this);
    });
```

Thanx every one who helped!

Solution: 
You can see from UPD2 that I have my function inside eventListener 'click'. What was happening is every time I pressed my input button it was reciving extra 'change' listener.

I changed .addListener for input to .addListenerOnce.

Comment: *"`rowData.push([input.files[i].name]);`"* Why are you pushing the filename as an *array*? I'd've expected just `rowData.push(input.files[i].name);` (no `[` and `]` around `input.files[i].name`).

Comment: It is so due to an array structure i am using. rowData is used to set the model of a table, array is one row of the table. And every next array i push will be next row in table. Each element in the [input.files[i].name] will be next column. For example [input.files[i].name, input.files[i].size]. I jusy cutted the stuff out to show code in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're not reloading the page, and you're not clearing out `rowData`. You haven't shown how/where you define `rowData`, but it would appear that the same instance of it is reused between calls to `showFiles`. (If you haven't declared it anywhere, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).)

---

From your comments below, it sounds like you want to keep the entries in `rowData`, but you want to only add *new* entries. If so, you'll need an explicit check:

```
var showFiles = function () {
    var input, i, file;

    input = document.getElementById('doc-upload');
    for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i += 1) {
        file = input.files[i].name;
        if (indexOfFile(rowData, file) === -1) {
            rowData.push([file]);
        }
    };
    console.log(rowData);
};

function indexOfFile(data, file) {
    var index;

    for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
        // Note that the 0 may need to be changed if the
        // `rowData.push([file])` line above doesn't put
        // the filename at index 0
        if (data[index][0] === file) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

Side note: You've said that the reason you're pushing an array rather than just the filename is that there's other information you're also including in that array but you left it out of your question. That's fine, but it may be delicate, see my note about index `0` above. You might consider using an array of objects instead:

```
rowData.push({
    file: file,
    other: "info",
    goes: "here"
});
```

...and then in `indexOfFile`:

```
if (data[index].file === file) {
```

That way, the code is less susceptible to breaking if you change the structure of what you're pushing.

Comment: I heve it declared right above 'var rowData = [];' I use layter in code to set data for my table model. (qooxdoo)

Comment: @user1869429: Then that's the problem, a single instance is reused every time you call `showFiles`. Either declare it *within* `showFiles` or put `rowData = [];` at the beginning of `showFiles` to get rid of the old information before adding the new information.

Comment: Crowde: I can't really do that. If i would get it cleared every time. My user would see only files they are uploaded last 'change'. But the might want to uplod few files in to the same array.

Comment: You are right. If i would clear the array before every change i guess it would work fine. It is just that i don't want to clear an array. But i might end up having separated array inside 'showFiles' function.

Comment: @user1869429: I'm still not 100% certain I understand what you're doing, but if you can't clear it out but you don't want duplicates, the only thing for it is to check whether the item you're adding already exists and only add it if it doesn't. I've updated the answer with an example of doing that.

Comment: It is not me who desided to use such an array structure. It is the framework i am using (qooxdoo) they have it for their table. I whant it to look like this [link](http://timofeybiryukov.kz/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/x.png). So user can see what did he uploaded and can delete it and such.

Comment: @user1869429: If it needs to be an array, that's fine, the main part of my update addressed that. You may just have to adjust the index used in `indexOfArray` (e.g., it may not be `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

```
rowData.push()
```

will just keep appending the elements to the end of your variable. You need to have a check if those inputs are already present.

(Edit-)

Try this:-

```
        rowData=[];
        var showFiles = function () {
        var input = document.getElementById('doc-upload');
        if (input.files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i += 1) {
              var f=[];
              for(var j=0;j<rowData.length;j++)
                 f.push(rowData[j][0]);
              if(f.indexOf(input.files[i].name) == -1)
                  rowData.push([input.files[i].name]);
            }
            console.log(rowData);
        };
    };
    document.getElementById('doc-upload').addEventListener('change', showFiles, this);
```

Comment: No it is not that. After i push them in to 'rowData' i display it to user. User may whant to have few simmilar files.What happaning is: i upload x.doc my array is [x.doc], now i want to upload y.doc. I choose y.doc and my array turns in to [x.doc, y.doc, y.doc], then i upload z.doc  and aaray looks like [x.doc, y.doc, y.doc, z.doc, z.doc, z.doc, z.doc]. And so on. It have to do some thing with length property, i messed it up some how.

Comment: Did you try with the code I gave? That actually checks for multiple file names in the array.

Your previous comment suggests you are reusing the push API multiple times.

Comment: I did. It acts the same. Here is screnshot of the interface [link](http://timofeybiryukov.kz/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/x.png)

Comment: Also, if you are not sure from where in your code the EXTRA elements are getting appended, you could make a general function for the push on rowData and call it from all the other places. The check if(rowData.indexOf(input.files[i].name) == -1) would make sure they are added just once.

Comment: I notice that you are pushing arrays to the variable instead of plain filename strings. Hope that you did modify the check condition accordingly.

Comment: I see and agree that this should work. But it is still acting the same. Only if i a might have done something wrong. Yes, i did added al of the extra elements that i have in my code. I will post full code as UPD.

Comment: Maybe you have not modified the check condition properly. Please check my revised code.